# Running macos application with root from AppleScript

Tags: macos, asp.net-core, applescript, root, sudo

I have a .netcore console application (wrapped in applicaton bundle to hide console during running) that add certificates to storage by invoking "security add-trusted-cert" command. Application should be launched with administrator privileges from browser with custom protocol. For that I created an AppleScript program that run my program if a user click a link with 'cerapp://' protocol.

```
on open location this_URL
    do shell script "osascript -e \"do shell script \\\"open '/opt/certapp/certapp.app'\\\" with administrator privileges\""
end open location
```

It seems that `osascript -e \"do shell script \\\"open` does run `open` command with administrator but not my application bundle.

Is there any way to run my bundle with administrator privileges with GUI password prompt?
I can't run my application from terminal.

Comment: You need to run the application's executable file (in `/Contents/MacOS/`).

Comment: I can't.Terminal window will be displayed.

Comment: Run the executable with the `do shell script` command instead of opening the app.

Comment: @red_menace, thank you. Is there any way to display my program name I want to run instead of "Script Editor need administrator privileges"?

Comment: @red_menace, my fault, application name is shown correctly. Thanks again